# Как убрать вертикальный скролл в CSS, но так, чтоб можно было бы прокручивать страницу вниз?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите, хочу убрать вертикальный скролл в css, но чтоб страницу можно было прокручивать вниз колесиком мыши

Comment: спрятать скролбар?

Comment: рабочий код покажите

Comment: Только вниз? Уточните вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

Вы не показали код, но могу дать такие css правила для того чтобы скрыть скроллбар и оставить возможность скролиинга

Существует правило CSS, которое может скрывать полосы прокрутки в браузерах на основе Webkit (Chrome и Safari). Это правило:

```
.element::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important }
```

Существует правило CSS, которое может скрывать полосы прокрутки в IE 10+. Это правило:

```
.element { -ms-overflow-style: none; }
```

Там раньше было  правило CSS , которые могли бы скрыть полосы прокрутки в Firefox, но с тех пор он считается устаревшим. Это правило было:

```
.element { overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; }
```

А чтобы убрать скроллбар со всей страницы

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0;}
```

[Источник](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kurlak/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari/)

Answer (score 2):

Если хочешь убрать скролбар , тогда вот код CSS :

```
html {
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
 }
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
  }
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background: #FF0000;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[подсмотрено здесь](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll-using-css/)

```js
for(let i=0; i<30;i++)
    "scroll me down".split(" ").map(function(d){ 
document.write(d+"<hr><hr><hr>")
});
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar { 
   width: 0 !important 
}
body { 
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none; 
  -ms-overflow-style: none; 
}
```

PS, `javascript` только для примера

Comment: в moz не работает и не работает в ie11, но работает в edge и chrome

Comment: @MaximLensky в ie починил, а вот мозилла пока не сдается =)

Answer (score 1):

Так как действия со скролл-баров плохо работает, то приходится использовать костыли, типо такого:

```css
.scroll-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #ddd;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scroll-wrap > .scroll {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 30px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-wrap">
  <div class="scroll">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque vulputate elit quam, nec venenatis urna dictum sed.</p>
    <p>Aenean ullamcorper magna a volutpat lobortis. Fusce cursus erat vitae hendrerit dignissim.</p>
    <p>Quisque sapien velit, tristique ac fermentum at, ornare ac nulla.</p>
    <p>Sed quis sapien sit amet ante tempus ultricies vitae eu mauris. Duis a rhoncus lectus.</p>
    <p>Vestibulum dapibus nunc massa, nec posuere purus tincidunt eget.</p>
    <p>Quisque rutrum lectus vulputate viverra laoreet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```